# auto find file directory path using PHP

Tags: php, path, relative-path

I upload file in my server and I have this url from my databse:

```
                  |---> subdomain for xammp in localhost windows
                  |
http://localhost/cms/uploads/files/1/final.mp4
```

Now for download i need to show file directory path of file like:

```
../cms/uploads/files/1/final.mp4 // This worked for subdomain
OR
./uploads/files/1/final.mp4 // This worked for domain root
```

how do auto find server path directory for file ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if in your URL you have "/cms/"

```
if (!strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/cms/')){
  $pathdir = '../cms/';
} else {
  $pathdir = './';
}
```